# "No pg_hba.conf entry for host localhost, user ADMIN, database SYSTEM"

Tags: postgresql, ibm-cloud, pgadmin

While trying to connect to my ElephantSQL database on Bluemix using pgadmin111, it throws the following error.

```
Access to database denied
The server doesn't grant access to the database: the server reports 
FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "XX.XXX.XX.XX", user "abcd", database "postgres", SSL on FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "XX.XXX.XX.XX", user "abcd", database "postgres", SSL off 
To access a database on a PostgreSQL server, you first have to grant primary access to the server for your client (Host Based Authentication). PostgreSQL will check the pg_hba.conf file if a pattern that matches your client address / username / database is present and enabled before any SQL GRANT access control lists are evaluated.
```

How can i access the pg_hba.conf file on bluemix?

Comment: x-posted to http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/108107/7788

Comment: Presumably you need to use SSL.